# Best way to run time to time PHP routines

Tags: php, cron

From time to time a customer or another ask me to program something that need to be executed from time to time.

For that I learned that cronjobs help, so I just call the PHP script, or the API call or anything by a `* * * * * wget url` on given tiem and that's it.

But I never checked if what I'm doing is the best way to do that.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried, and let us know as much information as possible as to why you believe it is not working.

Comment: Hi Mark, it's not a problem, it's a general question about what's the best way to do it. See, what I'm doing today may not be the best way to accomplish it, so I'm asking for thoughts about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the url for the php script, but make a php script that can be executed directly and execute that file directly from the command line.

```sh
* * * * * php /path/to/file.php
```

Comment: So, even if I'm working in a more complex system, you suggest that I create a single script that do the stuff in a more "procedural" style and call it?

Comment: Not a single script for each of the actions you need to undertake, but one per big action. Also, don't put all code in there, call your classes from this single script. This is how big frameworks like Laravel and Symfony take care of this.

Comment: Yes, but if you already have a web based app that is accessed by URL and takes get params etc.  then why not use it and call by URL?

Comment: @Jerodev I see, I use symfony for more complex development. Thank you, that another way to go.

Comment: @AbraCadaver There's not a why for not calling by URL. But I'm curious about other ways to do the same, or even more secure, more reliable methods for doing so. Actually calling by the URL is my main method to doing so.